# How can I convert comma separated string into a List<int>

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2"

List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',');
```

This doesn't work cause the split method returns a string[]

Answer (score 559, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: That could also be `List<int> TagIds = new List<int>(tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse));`

Comment: Is there a need for the `new List<>`?

Comment: @LiquidPony no; you could call `ToList()` instead; the result is essentially the same: `List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();`  You need to do one or the other, though, because the return value of `Select()` is an `IEnumerable<>`, but not a `List<>`

Comment: @LiquidPony in this implementation yes as the `Select` extension in this case returns `IEnumerable<Int32>` and it is not list. However list has a constructor accepting another collection as source.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you're welcome, but in response to your other comment, how is the result of `ToList<int>` not guaranteed to be the same as `List<int>`?

Comment: List isn't sealed; .ToList could return a subclass of List.

Comment: To handle the case where tags is an empty string, use `Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: How to do same thing but make a List<string> instead of List<int>?

Comment: Arrays.stream(tags.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()). @dasblinkenlight he asked for list of string, what you told is array of string

Answer (score 43):

If you want to include some simple validation and skip over invalid values (instead of throwing an exception), here's something that uses TryParse:

```
string csv = "1,2,3,4,a,5";
int mos = 0;
var intList = csv.Split(',')
                    .Select(m => { int.TryParse(m, out mos); return mos; })
                    .Where(m => m != 0)
                    .ToList();

//returns a list with integers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

**EDIT:** Here is an updated query based on feedback by Antoine. It calls TryParse first to filter out any bad values, and then Parse to do the actual conversion.

```
string csv = "1,2,3,4,a,5,0,3,r,5";
int mos = 0;
var intList = csv.Split(',')
                    .Where(m => int.TryParse(m, out mos))
                    .Select(m => int.Parse(m))
                    .ToList();

//returns a list with integers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 5
```

**Edit 2:** An updated query for C# 7.0, thanks to feedback from Charles Burns. Note that we get rid of the extra mos variable with this approach, so it's a bit cleaner.

```
string csv = "1,2,3,4,a,5,0,3,r,5";
var intList = csv.Split(',')
                 .Where(m => int.TryParse(m, out _))
                 .Select(m => int.Parse(m))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Fails if 0 is one legit input !

Comment: With C# 7.0 you can omit the declaration of mos and replace the TryParse call with `int.TryParse(m, out int _)`

Comment: can be further reduced to return str.Split(',').Where(m => int.TryParse(m, out int _)).Select(int.Parse).ToList();

Answer (score 18):

You can use LINQ w/ `int.Parse()` to convert the `string[]` to an `IEnumerable<int>` and then pass that result to the `List<T>` constructor:

```
var tagIds = new List<int>(tags.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)));
```

Answer (score 15):

Without LINQ Query , you can choose this method ,

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2";
List<string> numbers = nos.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

and then you can convert this List into integer type...

Comment: just a note to anyone not familiar = `.ToList<string>()` still needs `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 14):

A little LINQ goes a long way:

```
 List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',')
         .Select(t => int.Parse(t))
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2"

List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).Select(x=> Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number#example

You don't need to add `.Select(x => x.Trim()`, as Parse automatically trims any space characters for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C# 3.5 you can use Linq to achieve this

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2";
List<int> tagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(s=>int.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

or the short one

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2";
List<int> tagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string tags = "9,3,12,43,2";
List<int> TagIds = tags.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this and I just want to share my own solution without linq. This is a primitive approach. Non-integer values will not be added in the list also.

```
List<int> TagIds = new List<int>();
string[] split = tags.Split(',');
foreach (string item in split)
{
    int val = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(item, out val) == true)
    {
        TagIds.Add(val);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I made a modification to khalid13's answer. If the user put a string of "0", his answer would remove that from the resulting list. I did something similar but used an anonymous object.

```
var result = commaSeparatedString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(s => new { didConvert = int.TryParse(s.TrimNullProtection(), out convertedInt), convertedValue = convertedInt })
            .Where(w => w.didConvert)
            .Select(s => s.convertedValue)
            .ToList();
```

TrimNullProtection is a custom function I made that protects if the string is null.

What the above does is strip out any strings that were not able to be converted with no error. If you need to error if there was a problem with the conversion, then the accepted answer should do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

It's simple. First split the string.
Trim blank space present after comma(,).
Then use system defined ToList()

```
string inputText = "text1, text2"
```

To remove the space after ',' and convert this comma separated text to List

```
List<string> resultList = (inputText.Split(',')).Select(t => t).ToList();
```