# Convert comma separated values to list<string> through http pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In my API model binder get request I want to convert a comma separated string that is passed through the get request to a list. I want to only do it for once of the properties in my model so IModelBinder would not be the best to use, maybe a TypeConverter?

How would I go about doing this?

Some of you seem confused regarding m vague question. 
I want to add mapping within the http middleware not after the api call has been made.  There are numerous approaches such as the itypeconverter, action filter. This means  i will have to call the method over and over.

So if I have a API call called

```
public IActionResult getUserConfigs(List<string>UserIds, list<int> permmisionIds)
```

They send in a request e.g. UserIds=1,2,3,4,5, how do I plug in a middleware component to map the string to a list.

This needs to work in a dot net core project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/how-to-pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert comma separated string into a List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301268/how-can-i-convert-comma-separated-string-into-a-listint)

Comment: As I said in my question that I want to set up in a model binder approach and re-maps the input fields send over a http request e.g. userIds=1,2,3 to map it to a list.

Comment: Why do you send a JSON property `UserIds: '1,2,3,4,5'` instead of `UserIds: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? The latter will automatically bind to the `IList<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've supplied no details about what your model looks like, or any code at all, I'm going to construct a simple example to answer the question as I understand it...

This will receive a string value, separate it into an array and build an instance of a model from the separated values:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public void ReceiveUserString(string source)
{
    string[] UserString = source.Split(',');

    var User = new User();
    foreach (string u in UserString)
    {
        User.Username = u[0];
        User.Password = u[1];
    }
}
```

The `User` object can then be saved to your database or... whatever it is that you want to do with it on your API.

If you're getting a list of users, you'll need a second delimiter to split lines on:

```
string[] UsersFromString = source.Split('|');

foreach (string user in UsersFromString)
{
    var User = new User();
    string[] Fields = user .Split(',');

    User.Username = Fields[0];
    User.Password = Fields[1];
}
```

From your question:

> I want to convert a comma separated string that is passed through the get request to a list.

You can change the code slightly to have your output as a `List<User>`:

```
string[] UsersFromString = source.Split('|');

List<User> Users = new List<User>();
foreach (string user in UsersFromString)
{
    string[] Fields = user .Split(',');
    Users.Add(new User {User.Username = Fields[0], User.Password = Fields[1] });
}
```

Comment: That seems like a perfectly valid answer to a mostly vague question. Downvoters, please provide an argument as to which this answer could be improved.