# Convert comma separated string of ints into a List C++/cli

Tags: string, list, c++-cli

My starting point is a string separated by commas, containing a variable number of integers e.g.:

```
System::String^ tags=gcnew String("1,3,5,9");
```

Now I would like - with the least amount of steps possible - convert this string into a Integer list:

```
List<System::Int32>^  taglist= gcnew List<System::Int32>();//to contain 1,3,5,9
```

Additionally, after manipulating the list, I need to export it back to a string at the end of the day. I saw the question being asked for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301268/how-can-i-convert-comma-separated-string-into-a-listint)
but not for C++ which will be slightly different.

I tried directly initialize using the string, but that failed. I also tried .Split but that produces strings. I also dont want to do any complicated streamreader stuff. 
The answer in the link must have an equivalent for C++/cli.

Comment: `Split` creates an array of strings as you said, after that you want `Array::ConvertAll`

Answer (score 1):

As it mentioned in a comments you can use `Split` to convert the string to an array of strings, then you can use `Array::ConvertAll` to convert to an array of int values and after manipulating the values you can ise `String::Join` to convert an array of ints to a single string.

Here's a code sample:

```
String^ tags = gcnew String("1,3,5,9");
String^ separator = ",";
array<String^>^ tagsArray = tags->Split(separator->ToCharArray());

array<int>^ tagsIntArray = Array::ConvertAll<String^, int>(tagsArray,
    gcnew Converter<String^, int>(Int32::Parse));

// Do your stuff

String^ resultString = String::Join<int>(separator, tagsIntArray);
```

Comment: That would do the trick, but I would prefer to use a list instead of an array. With the answer I can easily get to and from a List:    List<System::Int32>^  taglist= gcnew List<System::Int32>(tagsIntArray);    and      String^ resultStringfromlist = String::Join<int>(separator, taglist);  BONUS question: can  I go to the list and back without the interim step of the array?

Comment: Yes and no :). I believe you'll need to create a `List<int>` object by yourself (just like you described), but at least you can pass this list to `String::Join<int>` method without converting back to `array<int>^`.