# How to wrap a list column in a view

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable with which one column is a list that is returned by a linq query.

The list look something like:

OFAC,EPLS,UNCON,IEO,EPLS,HHS,EPLS,HHS,EPLS,EPLS,HHS,IEO

I would like the column values to be separated on new lines by the commas.

I am not sure if I should be doing this on the back-end, or if I should be trying to accomplish this with CSS?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
  internal List<string> GetListTitles(long id_validation_results)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        using(var db = new fabitrack_validationEntities(ValidationConnString))
        {

            list =  db.ValidationSpecifics.Where(o => o.id_validation_results == o.id_validation_results)
                        .Select(o => o.title).ToList();
        }

        return list; 
    }


  <tbody>
                    @foreach (var o in Model.Results)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        @if (o.Person.FirstName == null || o.Person.FirstName == "" || o.Person.FirstName == "NOT")
                        {
                            <td>Not Found</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(o.Person.FirstName, "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
                        }
                        @if (o.Person.LastName == null || o.Person.LastName == "" || o.Person.LastName == "FOUND")
                        {
                            <td>Not Found</td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td>@Html.ActionLink(o.Person.LastName, "Detail", "Player", new { selectedPlayerID = o.Person.IDPerson, referringController = "ValidationHistory" }, null)</td>
                        }
                        <td>@o.Person.SocialSecurityNumber</td>
                        <td>@o.Validation_Results.IRSOk</td><!--IRS/TIN-->
                        <td>@o.Validation_Results.DMFOk</td><!--DMF Details-->
                        <td>@o.Validation_Results.ListOk</td><!--List Matches-->
                        <td>@o.Validation_Results.ExecutedAt<!--Executed At-->
                        <td>@o.Validation_Results.ExecutedBy</td><!--Executed By-->
                        <td>@o.Person.ClubID</td>
                        <td id="listcol">@o.ListMatches</td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

And then some CSS I have tried..

```
#listcol {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+ */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: wrap column; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    flex-flow: wrap column;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not drive the display logic with commas (,) and CSS. This is an anti-pattern. In the future you might need to change the separator like comma to a semicolon. Instead send the data as a list from the controller.

You can use the following code as answered here: [How can I convert comma separated string into a List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301268/how-can-i-convert-comma-separated-string-into-a-listint)

```
string csv = "1,2,3,4,a,5,0,3,r,5";
int mos = 0;
var intList = csv.Split(',')
                    .Where(m => int.TryParse(m, out mos))
                    .Select(m => int.Parse(m))
                    .ToList();
```

**//returns a list with integers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 5**

Now you have a list of integers. Same you can do for strings. Just change the data types and remove the `int.TryParse` and `int.Parse` in the query.

Then on the UI just loop through the list and render the data as you need.